# Symbol datatype in C++

Tags: c++, symbols

Some langauges contain a construct to express immutable symbols. E.g., in Ruby symbol literals have the form: `:symbolName`. Then it is, e.g., possible to use them to efficiently retrieve a value from a map (`error_count[:syntax_errors]`) and moreover they can be easily converted into strings (`:syntax_error.to_s`). My experience is that this creates very well readable and maintainable code.

Is there something similar available in C++ (I don't want want to use integer constants because I need to declare them and they cannot be easily converted into strings; I don't want to run a script over my source files prior to compilation which does some fancy substitutions)? I am looking for a solution using the C preprocessor or some tricks from meta template programming.

Comment: You're thinking of an enumerated type.  Unfortunately, in C++, they require a bit of boilerplate code if you plan on converting them into strings.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to use enums either. I want to declare and write as less as possible.

Comment: I found this: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#stringliteral which will help when all things-to-be-symbols are `const`, but AFAIK that limits you to symbols you type in. No `"foo".to_sym`. However, I think there's a way to combine the two methods. Let me get back to you on this.

Comment: To be clear, the desired functionality is: Some way to turn string literals into "symbols", some way to turn run-time strings into "symbols", some way to turn "symbols" back into their strings. Maximize the interoperability with existing C++ stuff, the performance/optimizability - which is the point of symbols in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a std::unordered_map<> in C++11, but since you are talking about "symbol literals" you can actually do this much better with static symbols. The simples way is with straight C and the C preprocessor.

```
#define declare_literal(x) const char x[] = #x
declare_literal(foo); //now "foo" is a global symbol you can use everywhere
```

That doesn't provide the single instance guarantee you might be looking for. That is actually trickier to accomplish than one might hope, but you can do it with some ugliness:

```
template <typename CharType, CharType... args>
struct symbol_base {
    using self_type = symbol<CharType, args...>;
    static constexpr std::size_t char_length = sizeof...(args) / sizeof(CharType);
    static constexpr CharType value[char_length] = {CharType(args)...};
    static const std::string& as_string() { static const std::basic_string<CharType> val{value, char_length}; return val; }
    operator const std::string&() const { return as_string(); }
};

template <char... args>
using symbol = symbol_base<char, args...>;

template <wchar_t... args>
using wsymbol = symbol_base<wchar_t, args...>;
```

So then you can make a symbol for "foo" with:

```
symbol<'f', 'o', 'o'> foo;
```

Not exactly elegant, but effective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The C defines are already OK for my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There are no [symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_%28programming%29) in C++, because compile time and run time are different worlds.

You could however play some preprocessor tricks (see [X_macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19217972/841108), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25412862/841108), etc...

So you might have a file defining your symbols like e.g.

```
 // file my-symbols.def
 MY_SYMBOL(a)
 MY_SYMBOL(foo)
 #undef MY_SYMBOL
```

and you would use it several times, e.g. once to declare some enum:

```
enum my_symbols_en {
#define MY_SYMBOL(N) sy_##N,
#include "my-symbols.def"
};
```

<sup>If you don't like `enum`-s use a similar trick to declare something different, e.g. static instances...</sup>

and once to e.g. define the output routine

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, my_symbols_en symb) {
  switch (symb) {
#define MY_SYMBOL(Sy) case sy_##N: out << #Sy ; break;
#include "my-symbols.def"
  default: std::cerr << "bad symbol" << std::endl; exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return out;
}
```

and likewise for input, hashing, string-conversion, etc, etc...

You could also use specialized C++ generating scripts in your build framework. For instance, the `my-symbols.def` might be generated by some `awk` script...

Answer (score 1):

The `enum` construct is built for this.

[Some good example for using enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564322/some-good-example-for-using-enums)

If you would like a hash map, consider std::unordered_map

[Simple hashmap implementation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266206/simple-hashmap-implementation-in-c)

Comment: I don't want to use enums, I am looking for something that comes close to the Ruby style.

Comment: There's no `std::hash_map` in the standard library.

Comment: I know that it is possible to do amazing things using CPP and template meta programming (e.g., in the boost library). I am wondering whether anyone has ever applied those concepts to this problem.

Comment: apology there, @quanddev std::unordered_map http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Comment: Symbols exist in Ruby for an efficiency issue that C++ doesn't have.  If you want to reference the same thing in different places, without making copies of that thing, use pointers.